# gulp Segmentation fault: 11 and Abort trap: 6 OSX Yosemite

Tags: node.js, macos, gulp, browser-sync

We've been running on gulp with a set of tasks, with browser-sync and gulp.watch to reload the browser when files are changed. Increasingly I've been seeing more and more `Segmentation fault: 11` and `Abort trap: 6` intermittently on 2 different projects.

The gulp task layout is a derivative of this: https://github.com/notbrain/viceroy

I really have no idea where to start pinpointing the culprit besides whittling down the set of tasks to run until I run into the issue when only running a single task via watch and browser-sync.

So, this is mainly a plea for help if someone else has seen this issue

> Abort trap 6 example

```
[BS] File changed: build/views/admin/dashboard/adminSailingCalls.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/admin/dashboard/adminSailingLanes.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/admin/dashboard/adminUsers.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/admin/dashboard/index.html
[16:58:32] Starting 'html-index'...
[16:58:32] Finished 'html-index' after 1.3 ms
[16:58:32] Starting 'html'...
[16:58:33] Finished 'html' after 74 ms
[16:58:33] Starting 'html-index'...
[16:58:33] Finished 'html-index' after 1.88 ms
[16:58:33] Starting 'html'...
gulp(79700,0x1094e8000) malloc: *** error for object 0x108f19bc0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

> Segfault: 11 example:

```
[BS] File changed: build/views/sailingsSearchStep1.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/sailingsSearchStep2.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/sailingsSearchStep3Container.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/sailingsSearchStep3Weight.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/searchSubmitted.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/signup.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/signupStep1.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/signupStep2.html
[BS] File changed: build/views/signupStep3.html
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've seen issues with similar end results when gulp-sass tried to parse empty .scss files, but we are using .less. Any guidance is greatly appreciated - while the project above is still usable, I have started another side project that has significantly fewer files but I see the `Segfault: 11` bug so much that I'm considering a move to an [npm script based workflow](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) to work it out.

Comment: Start by clearing out `node_modules/` in your project directory and running `npm install` again. Both errors suggest issues with either Node.js or with any compiled add-ons (I've been running Node on Yosemite for ages and for lots of different projects and never got any kills like that). Also try to make sure that you're not hitting some sort of memory limit (`ulimit -a`).

Comment: @robertklep Have already done this repeatedly, and also used salita to upgrade everything to latest. Also have 32GB of RAM so I don't think a memory limit would be an issue, usage is very minimal but I should run iStat.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling gulp locally in project folder helped for me, not sure why. However, since it's basically risk-free, one can give it a try:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```